# Values not being passed between fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, tabs, android-activity

I have a tabbed layout with 2 tabs. Each tab can collect some data in the form of a double, such as 52.363. When a button is pressed in any one of the tabs, they open a new activity which displays the numbers entered within the previous tab. However, when I press the submit button, a value does not show up. Any ideas as to why?

Fragment Tab code (both tabs are the same for now, also parts that are self-explanatory are left out):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.advfrag_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    inSnow = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.inchesSnow);
    calc = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
    results = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.resultView);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try{
                        inchSnow = Double.parseDouble(inSnow.getText().toString());
                    }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                        results.setText("Field Blank!");

                    }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), ResultPost.class);
                intent.putExtra("inchSnow", inchSnow);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

The activity that the data is sent to, ResultPost.Class (Again, only essential parts):

```
public class ResultPost extends ActionBarActivity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_post);
        AdvancedFragment advancedFragment= new AdvancedFragment();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        double inchesn = intent.getDoubleExtra("inchSnow", 0);
    }
}
```

The ResultPost.Class goes on to change a textview to show this data, but the value of the textview remains at "0", which is the default value even when I have given it a different value such as 6.

Comment: You've verified that `intent.putExtra("inchSnow", inchSnow);` puts the correct value?

Comment: How can I verify this? I have defined the double `inchSnow` as a value in the program but it never shows up in `ResultPost.Class`. I do know that `inchSnow` has a value associated with it as I have a `TextView` in the fragment that shows the values of the inputs for testing purposes.

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code and check the value put into the intent?

Comment: Don't use getActivity().getBaseContext(), use getActivity(), that alone is a valid context.

Comment: @Szymon Thank you so much for reminding me to step through the code. I quickly found a silly mistake on my part! Is there anyway to delete this question?

Comment: I think not because it has one vote up. You can answer your own question though.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this  :

```
public class ResultPost extends ActionBarActivity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_post);
        AdvancedFragment advancedFragment= new AdvancedFragment();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        double inchesn = intent.getDoubleExtra("inchSnow",0.0);
    }
}
```